# Redirect to a view Action Filter Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

How can I redirect logged in users (in every page) to a view asking them to complete their info?

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
 {
    if (userIsLoggedIn)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(userInfoView);
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect to a view, you need to redirect to an action method and that action method would return the view:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (userIsLoggedIn)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToAction("UserInfoActionName", "UserInfoControllerName");
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

[This blog](https://debugmode.net/2014/10/10/redirecttoaction-or-view-as-actionresult-in-asp-net-mvc5/) explains exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

RedirectToAction is avaible in MVC Core. I archived this as follows in MVC 4:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   if (!condition)
   {
      filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
      new RouteValueDictionary{ { "controller", "YourController" },
                                { "action", "YourAction" }
                              });
   }
}
```

This will redirect you to the given action then to the relevant view.